# How to save into the mysql database in in-app-purchase using webservices in CN1

Tags: codenameone

I was following the tutorial of AUTO-RENEWING SUBSCRIPTIONS IN IOS AND ANDROID on CN1 Blog. When I click on Subscribe 1 month No Ads, I received the message "Thanks for subscribing". I went ahead to check my subscription maybe it has been inserted into the database but I met empty record, which means it did not saved. Pls what can I do about this. Though I am suspecting the step in the tutorial that says:

Setting up the Server Project
Download the CN1-IAP-Server demo project from Github, and run its "install-deps" ANT task in order to download and install its dependencies to your local Maven repo.

1 For the following commands to work, make sure you have "ant", "mvn", and "git"        in your environment PATH.
2 $ git clone https://github.com/shannah/cn1-iap-demo-server
3 $ cd cn1-iap-demo-server
4 $ ant install-deps

When I was following the tutorial, I omitted. No 1, 2, 3 and 4 as numbered aboved.
I did not know how to locate this on my system, am doubting maybe as a result of this that is why I can not save.

**Am I correct with the environment path in windows 8 with the image below?**
[image]
If yes, I want to add the code below into the environment part.

```
 $ git clone https://github.com/shannah/cn1-iap-demo-server
 $ cd cn1-iap-demo-server
 $ ant install-deps
```

am I correct with the image below?
[image]
If the above steps are wrong, I need more light on this. pls help am seriously battling with this.

Answer (score 0):

Those emitted steps are pretty important. Without them you don't have a server to proxy your connection to mysql.

Comment: Pls sir. how do I locate environment path? I am really sorry for this question. Thanks Sir

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789807/how-to-locate-environment-path-in-codename-one/41799456#41799456

Comment: I really appreciate your response. Sir, help to review my question above maybe you will understand my question better. Thanks for your errort

Comment: Those are instructions for Unix/Linux not for windows, since I don't have a windows machine here I can't really give you accurate instructions but it seems you are mixing the path statement and the command line that should be given

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have unserstood what you want to do but if you want to clone a github repository with windows just install this tool:

https://git-scm.com/download/win

Be sure to check the right checkbox if you want to use git commands in your windows shell. You can also use the git shell if you want to.

Once installed just go to your workspace directory and use `git clone projectURL`.
To build the project i suggest you open the project in eclipse and build it from here using the ant file. You'll may have to edit the pom.xml.

Comment: Jonas, I am very grateful for your concern. I will get back to you with what I get after trying your answer.