# How to locate environment path in codename one

Tags: codenameone

For the following commands to work, make sure you have "ant", "mvn", and "git" in your environment PATH.
pls I need to add the following to the environment part.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/shannah/cn1-iap-demo-server
$ cd cn1-iap-demo-server
$ ant install-deps.
```

I dont know how to locate environment path on my system. pls help

Answer (score 0):

That's Unix/Linux and unrelated to Codename One. One would setup an environment path as such:

```
export PATH=/path/to/ant/binary:$PATH
```